# Is there a database that accepts special characters by default (without converting them)?

Tags: sql, database, character-encoding, special-characters

I am currently starting from scratch choosing a database to store data collected from a suite of web forms. Humans will be filling out these forms, and as they're susceptible to using international characters, especially those humans named José and François and أسامة and 布鲁斯, I wanted to start with a modern database platform that accepts all types (so to speak), without conversion.

Q: Does a databases exist, from the start, that accepts a wide diversity of the characters found in modern typefaces? If so, what are the drawbacks to a database that doesn't need to convert as much data in order to store that data?

// **Anticipating two answers that I'm not looking for:**

I found many answers to how someone could CONVERT (or encode) a special character, like é or a copyright symbol © into database-legal character set like `&#169;` (for ©) so that a database can then accept it. This requires a conversion/translation layer to shuttle data into and out of the database. I know that has to happen on a level like the letter z is reducible to 1's and 0's, but I'm really talking about finding a human-readable database, one that doesn't need to translate.

I also see suggestions that people change the character encoding of their current database to one that accepts a wider range of characters. This is a good solution for someone who is carrying over a legacy system and wants to make it relevant to the wider range of characters that early computers, and the early web, didn't anticipate. I'm not starting with a legacy system. I'm looking for some modern database options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are databases that support large character sets. How to accomplish this is different from one database to another. For example:

- In MS SQL Server you can use the `nchar`, `nvarchar` and `ntext` data types to store Unicode (UCS-2) text.
- In MySQL you can choose UTF-8 as encoding for a table, so that it will be able to store Unicode text.

For any database that you consider using, you should look for Unicode support to see if can handle large character sets.

Comment: Hi @Guffa. As I understand, Unicode is a standard which aims to provide a consistent reference set for most every character. If it stores © as `U+00A9` then two Unicode-supporting databases can exchange a `U+00A9` easily, with conversion to/from © only when pushed to a display interface. I'm wondering if there's a database scheme that stores © as © and sends it to another database as ©, so it never converts, and so that it is always human-readable? Like XML stores data. (Though XML does need to "escape" 5 illegal characters: & " ' < >.)

Comment: @Perre: Text is always stored as numbers, regardless if you are using Unicode or any other character set. Unicode is a superset of ASCII, so for example the character `A` is stored as `0x41` in both. Whichever encoding you choose to work with, the data has to be decoded to get it as text, and any interface that you use to get ASCII text out of the database should also be capable of getting Unicode text.

Comment: I definitely get that on a base level, a computer does not store a capital `A` as `A`. If the computer is modern, it may store `A` in 16-bit Unicode as: `0000 0000 0100 0001`. But there's a middle-layer of ASCII where you said `A` is stored as `0x41`.So you know of no modern database that uses the same character on the interface layer when saving to the middle layer, i.e. just stores `A` as `A`?

Comment: @Perre: `0x41` is the same as `01000001`, it's just a different way to represent a numerical value. There is no middle layer.